# Iterative DFS -- where to mark a node as visited?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

This is my implementation of iterative dfs based on some suggestions that I've seen on here stating to mark a node as visited as soon as it is added to the stack.

I've looked at some other implementations such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-depth-first-traversal/ where a node is marked as visited after it is removed from the stack. Most implementations I've seen marks it as visited after it is removed from the stack. What is the advantage of implementing it this way over what I have done? In this version, it looks like you still go through the for loop even if you have already visited the current node. In my version, you would never run into a case where the for loop is executed for a visited node.

Upon further looking at my current code, I see that I mark it as visited before putting it into the stack. Would the correct way be to mark it as visited after putting it into the stack?

```
#include <iostream>


#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void dfs_iterative(const std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> &adj_list, 
   const int source, const int target)
{
   if(source == target) return;
    unordered_set<int> visited;

   std::stack<int> st;

   st.emplace(source);
   visited.emplace(source);

   while(!st.empty())
   {
      auto head = st.top();
      st.pop();

      cout << head << endl;

      for(const auto &neighbor : adj_list.at(head)) 
      {
         if(visited.find(neighbor) == visited.end())
         {
            visited.emplace(neighbor);
            st.emplace(neighbor);
         }
      }
   }
}

int main( ) 
{ 
    unordered_map<int, vector<int>> adj_list;
    adj_list[0] = {1};
    adj_list[1] = {2,3};
    adj_list[2] = {3};
    adj_list[3] = {2};

    dfs_iterative(adj_list, 0, 11);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not actually do DFS. For what you do, the difference is not relevant, think what would happen, if you wanted to create a DFS Tree (so you would save all used edges). Consider The following (undirected) graph:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
     |---------|     <- connection between B and D
```

Now we start DFS at node A. The following would happen:

```
head | st     | used edge | saved edges
A    | B      |           |
B    | C, D   | A -- B    | A -- B
C    | D      | B -- C    | A -- B, B -- C
D    |        | B -- D    | A -- B, B -- C, B -- D
```

The relevant part is, that you use `B -- D`, since you mark `D` the first time you happen upon it. So your DFS tree would look like this:

```
A -- B -- C
     |
     D
```

which is wrong. It should look like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D          // C and D can be exchanged
```

Is this relevant? For certain applications of the DFS it is. For just finding a node on some way, it is irrelevant, you will still muster the whole graph in this way. Indeed, DFS is mostly used as just an easy graph mustering algorithm, so the edges used a probably unimportant for almost all applications. (Actually I can right now only think of one where it is important)

Comment: Doesn't my code come across the edge C -- D before the edge B -- D?

Comment: No, think about from which node D is visited. B is certainly before C and D and since we go through all neighbors of B, we add the edges to C and D when we are looking at B. We see D as a neighbor from C before we really visit D, but it is already marked when we do that, so we wouldn't add this edge.

Comment: But that depends on the ordering of the adjacency list. If D comes before C when we're looping through the neighbors of B, then we visit edge B -- D first. But if C comes before D, then we visit B -- C first, and then C -- D.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I see what you're saying. Let me think about this some more.